# MS SQL How CONTAINSTABLE function operates the given search string?

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I am trying MS SQL Full Text Query on single column.

For this I am using "CONTAINSTABLE " function.

Following is my store procedure:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[USP_Videos_SearchVideos_ContainsTable]
    @searcher varchar(2000)

AS

DECLARE @SearchString varchar(2000)

SET @SearchString = 'FormsOf(INFLECTIONAL, "' + @searcher + '")'

SELECT *

FROM table_name AS v 
    INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(table_name, TitleText, @SearchString) AS Ranker 
        ON v.ID = Ranker.[KEY] 
    INNER JOIN mst_Categories AS c 
        ON v.CategoryId = c.ID 


WHERE RANKER.RANK >= 100 

ORDER BY Ranker.RANK DESC, v.ViewCount DESC
```

I could pass the entire "search string", but the result contains only those videos which contains the "search string" completely into their "video title" .

This is not expected, instead it should return result set which contains the inflectional words as well, as I am using "FormsOf" in my stored procedure.

Please comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

[Supported Forms of Query Terms (Full-Text Search)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879300%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) shows the supported query forms:

> **Inflectional forms of a specific word (generation term)**: The inflectional forms are the different tenses of a verb or the singular and plural forms of a noun.

A little more details at [Searching for the Inflectional Form of a Specific Word](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142566%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> You can search for all the different tenses of a verb or both the singular and plural forms of a noun. For example, the query shown in this topic searches for any form of "foot" ("foot", "feet", and so on)

So you see, you can search for inflections of a **single word** (a verb or a noun), not a phrase. That is, `FORMSOF(..,"search")'`  or `'FORMSOF(..,"string")'` but not `FORMSOF(..,"search string")'`